# Implementing a custom donation amount with Stripe Checkout

Tags: wordpress, server, stripe-payments

I have a simple WordPress setup which has a donations page. I have used some basic Stripe Checkout buttons which will allow for set amounts to be donated. I have set these up as products in the Stripe Dashboard. However, I am looking into the option of including a custom amount option, where users can type the amount they wish to donate. But from what I have read, this requires a more advanced setup. I'm not entirely clued up on server side interactions but I believe there has to be some kind of server involvement to achieve a custom donation amount.

I have seen code that would be implemented on the front end ( The form fields, for example) but where would I need to implement the server code?

Can anybody give me a little guidance on this. Any help much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, I'm not sure what your technical background is so I cannot advise you on how you would go about it. You might have to hire a developer or ask a friend to help you build your Stripe integration out, or use a Stripe Partner from their Partner Program that can act as a plugin/platform for your Wordpress site: https://stripe.com/partners/apps-and-extensions

Ultimately Stripe's docs mostly cover how you would go about integrating Stripe into a backend: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Your webpage would have to send a request with the custom donation amount, to your server, to create a CheckoutSession for a custom Price of that amount: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#add-an-event-handler-to-the-checkout-button

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Stripe Checkout, then there's really no need to do any server-side development. Since you've set up Products and Prices in Stripe dashboard, then all you need is to use Stripe Checkout client-only integration, and pass in the respective items ID https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout?type=cardNumber#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems